# Android OpenGL ES draw_texture with cropping or VBO's?

Tags: android, opengl-es, crop, vbo, atlassprites

Hey all, i was re-working my android app to use OpenGL instead of canvas (as it is ungodly slow) and i was wondering, since i'm using a tile sheet (atlas texture) would it be faster to use VBO's or draw_texture with the crop set like so:

```
// Crop our texture
((GL11) gl).glTexParameteriv(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, cropRect[cropIndex], 0);
gl.glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
```

After listening a while to Chris Pruett I gathered that draw_texture is undoubtably the fastest for an individual sprite but if i am cropping an atlas is this still true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> would it be faster to use VBO's or draw_texture

[image: Draw using atlas texture]

Note that he is using a "tiled world" which explains why he is using this technique. If you're not using a tiled world you should probably go with `draw_texture`.

> After listening a while to Chris Pruett I gathered that draw_texture is undoubtably the fastest for an individual sprite but if i am cropping an atlas is this still true?

Not always. If you're using a big atlas texture with many sprites the `glTexParameteriv()` function will be too expensive. If you're just using a lower amount of sprites it will probably be faster, which also depends on number of calls to the `glTexParameteriv()` function.

Comment: Well to give you an idea my atlas is 1024x1024 and at most i have about 12 sprites on screen (non static) And they do not make up a world, the "world" is a simple background image.

Thanks so much for the great reply btw!

Comment: @Alex: Then you're probably good with using `draw_texture` and `glTexParameteriv()`.

Comment: Thanks! But if i wanted to implement say, a particle system would that be best with a vbo setup?

Comment: @Alex: You can go with `draw_texture`. I don't see a performance reason if I should go the VBO way.

Comment: Thanks for all your help really! Just for future reference, when would i want to go with the VBO approach? I mean these particle systems would be spawning 20-30 particles, but still draw texture with crop?

Comment: @Alex: You should go with the VBO approach when `draw_texture` isn't available.

Comment: Okay, how needed is this would you say? Is draw_texture standard in openGL 2.0? I mean 2.0+ is nearly 90% of the market, and lower phones usually support it as well...

Comment: @Alex: I don't know about standardizations in 2.0, but in 1.0 it's not always guaranteed to be available. With some logic thinking it should be standard in 2.0, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Alright perhaps i'll start another question for that. Thank you so much!